# How to execute a command which has multiple arguments on every line of a matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have tried the below command:

```
while read line;
do
    $(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2)
    echo '$line'
done <<< $(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument3) | grep Off | awk '{print $1,$3}'
```

To explain (my assumptions):

the below command will be executed and the result is passed to grep command to filter for matching lines with text 'Off' and then printing column 1 and 3.

```
$(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument3) | grep Off | awk '{print $1,$3}'
```

All the information of column 1 and 3 should be passed to a while loop which reads every line and executes the command on each line.

```
while read line
do
    $(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2)
    echo '$line'
done <<<
```

Comment: better off if you can provide some sample outputs from both `$(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argumenmt2)` and `$(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument3) | grep Off | awk '{print $1,$3}'`

Comment: I need to say, that your `$( ....)` construct is quite brave, but certainly possible, but aside from this - what is your question?

Comment: The output of your while loop is being piped to `grep Off | awk '{print $1,$3}'`.  The input of your loop is the output of `usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument 3`

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this

```
while read arg1 arg2;
do
    /usr/bin/xyz arg1 arg2;
done < <(/usr/bin/xyz otherargument1 otherargument3 | awk '/Off/{print $1,$3}')
```

note that there is no line, since two arguments are passed in to the while block.

Also, there is no need for `grep`, since you already have `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify the code without changing the logic:

```
while read line; do
    $(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2)
    echo "$line"
done <<< $(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument3) | awk '/Off/ {print $1, $3}'
```

Some notes about oddities in this code:

```
    echo "$line"
```

I changed the quotes from single (`'`) to double (`"`) since with single quotes, it will always output `$line` (literally) whereas with double quotes, it will output the contents of that variable.

```
$(/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2)
```

This will run `/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2`, get the output, and then evaluate it.  This may be a security risk if you can't properly control what might be run.  For example, let's say `/usr/bin/xyz` was effectively `echo`.  Then we could have:

```
$(echo argument1 argument2)
```

This means the `while` loop will try to *execute* `argument1` with option `argument2`.  Is this what you want?

What do you intend the [herestring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings) (`<<<`) to do?  I'm guessing you don't want any of the `$(…)` wrappers nor do you want the herestring, but it's hard to guess given the mysterious `xyz` program.

What does this do:

```
/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument3 | while read line; do
    /usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2
    echo "$line"
done | awk '/Off/ {print $1, $3}'
```

Perhaps `awk` was supposed to modify the input?  In that case, try:

```
/usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument3 | awk '/Off/ {print $1, $3}' \
    | while read line; do
        /usr/bin/xyz argument1 argument2
        echo "$line"
done
```